# Can't drag/drop objects in View Controller unless zoomed

Tags: xcode, io

I've seen many videos of people working with xcode 4+ in which they can drag/drop objects onto their views with no problem (e.g @2:20 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=It2fAolaFV0). I, on the other hand, have to select the View Controller of interest, and zoom in a crazy amount before I can drag/drop objects onto it (until I can't see anything but background of UIView)

I can't seem to find any preference for this (or information on it), so thought I might ask here. Does anyone know how to change this?

Comment: Was trying at least an hour to drag anything at all into my view. Thanks for the solution -- zooming way, way in.

Comment: I have the exact same problem and came up with the same solution as you, but even then I ended up in a situation where it doesn't accept drag/drops and it gives absolutely no explanation as to why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ah, here we are two years later and XCode 5.1 exhibits the same behavior.

Double click anywhere on the storyboard - the editor will zoom to the correct level for placing objects.

Answer (score 12):

No there is no way of changing this.
You have to zoom the view to one view controller to be able to drag and drop controls.

Answer (score 2):

The Storyboard view has to be at 100% in order to add elements. This is a limitation of the Storyboard implementation. You can get the ViewController you are working on to zoom and center by double-clicking on it's icon in the bottom bar under it.

File a bug/feature request to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/bugbestpractices.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to zoom in first but instead of using the zoom+ and zoom- buttons, simple double click on the particular view controller and it will just to the required size for dragging objects.