# Cannot drag and drop image from Media library onto a view controller in Xcode Interface Builder

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop, interface-builder

I'd like to [reference this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437703/cant-drag-drop-objects-in-view-controller-unless-zoomed), but even though I am zoomed in to a view controller, on some occasions there is just no way of adding drag-dropping an image from the Media library onto a view controller. What's going on? Xcode 6.3.2.

Answer (score 1):

When this does not work, I have found out that closing and opening the right tab (Utilities) does help. It's like it does not refresh the contents of the media library properly if not doing this close-open trick. I can confirm that this problem is still in Xcode 6.4 that was released yesterday.